# Codeacademy React Syntax vs Official Tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In Codeacademy, this is the sample syntax for writing react components

```
var Input = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      userInput: ''
    };
  },

  handleUserInput: function (e) {
    this.setState({
      userInput: e.target.value
    });
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          onChange={this.handleUserInput}
          value={this.state.userInput}  />
        <h1>{this.state.userInput}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

It generally like looks a basic Javascript object with various attributes, which makes sense to me.

Here is an example from the react official tutorial

```
    class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm new to Javascript and React so the second approach makes less sense to me.  Can someone help walk me through how something like `class NameForm extends React.Component` might compare to something like `var Input = React.createClass`?  Also, would love to know if there are any more basic tutorials that teach react using the syntax from the official tutorial (that explains the syntax at a basic level as it goes along)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First example is **ECMAScript 5**, second one is **ECMAScript 6**

[Here](http://es6-features.org/) you can find the list of changes between them.

To run **React on ECMAScript 6** you should use Babel but first of all I would recommend:

[ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html) has well-written documentation, first - do "Hellow Word" App with it.